# Is there a way I can speed up this code or is this the fastest it'll go?

Tags: python, django

I have a function that's running in Django. It's supposed to calculate distance of a location based on user location. It works, the only problem is I feel my current implementation may be lacking in performance. It tends to take quite a bit of time. Here's the code:

```
def resolve_near_by_branches(self, info, **kwargs):
    ul_raw = kwargs.get('user_location')
    ul_l = ul_raw.split(',')
    user_location = (float(ul_l[0]), float(ul_l[1]))

    final_b = []

    if kwargs.get('category') is None:
        es = Establishment.objects.distinct().all()
    else:
        es = Establishment.objects.distinct().filter(
            category__code_name__exact=kwargs.get('category'),
        )

    for e in es:
        for branch in e.branches.all():
            b_l = (float(branch.location.latitude.replace(' ', "")), float(branch.location.longitude.replace(' ', "")))
            # if geodesic(user_location, b_l).km < 9000000:
            final_b.append((geodesic(user_location, b_l).m, branch))

    final_data = sorted(final_b, key=lambda x: x[0])
    print(final_data)
    # print([i[1] for i in final_b])

    return [i[1] for i in final_data]
```

If you have any suggestions on how I can speed this up, please contribute.

Comment: If you have working code, you should consider to post your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. You might need to provide a [mcve] though.

Comment: How should we know if there is a faster way to implement your function when we don't know what it is doing. We can't get what it is doing, because the indents are wrong (first line) and they are important in python. Please fix.

Comment: There are several things there that look like they will cause unnecessary queries, but without seeing your models it's hard to help you properly.

Comment: You probably don't need to sort the full list. If you only need the top N users nearby. Use the `heapq` module to track the top N instead.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious improvement, since you are accessing what appears to be a reverse relationship on each iteration, is to use [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). This tells Django to do one extra database query at evaluation to retrieve the reverse relationship rather than doing one each time it is accessed, which results in much fewer queries.

```
def resolve_near_by_branches(self, info, **kwargs):
    ul_raw = kwargs.get('user_location')
    ul_l = ul_raw.split(',')
    user_location = (float(ul_l[0]), float(ul_l[1]))

    final_b = []

    if kwargs.get('category') is None:
        es = Establishment.objects.distinct().all()
    else:
        es = Establishment.objects.distinct().filter(
            category__code_name__exact=kwargs.get('category'),
        )

    for e in es.prefetch_related('branches'):
        for branch in e.branches.all():
            b_l = (float(branch.location.latitude.replace(' ', "")), float(branch.location.longitude.replace(' ', "")))
            # if geodesic(user_location, b_l).km < 9000000:
            final_b.append((geodesic(user_location, b_l).m, branch))

    final_data = sorted(final_b, key=lambda x: x[0])
    print(final_data)
    # print([i[1] for i in final_b])

    return [i[1] for i in final_data]
```

I made a [Django ORM optimization cheat sheet](http://concisecoder.io/2018/11/04/django-orm-optimization-tips/) recently that you may find helpful when looking for quick optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But won't asking Django to make one extra query slow the function down?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. When you iterate through a queryset (`for e in es`), Django makes one database query to evaluate it. When you use `prefetch_related()`, it does another database query at this point and joins the reverse relationship in Python. If you don't use `prefetch_related()`, it doesn't do this extra query and instead makes a query each time you access the reverse relationship (`e.branches.all()`), which results in a lot more queries.

Comment: There are tools that you can use to profile your django application during development. This helps you identify and analyze performance bottlenecks. Check out django-debug-toolbar or django-silk. https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/developer-tools/